# How to run pkgdown for YAML to take effect?

Tags: devtools, pkgdown

Can somebody please help me understanding how to change the url, and, for example, the author on pkgdown sites?

https://pkgdown.r-lib.org/reference/build_site.html

Hypothetically I placed this the yml as 
    inst/_pkgdown.yml

Adding these lines

```
url: http://iotables.ceemid.eu`

authors:
  Daniel Antal, CFA:
  href: "http://www.twitter.com/antaldaniel"`
```

And eventually I put in the setup options

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>",
  fig.path = "man/figures/"
  #fig.path = "README-"
 )
```

furthermore placed  in `README.Rmd`

```
# iotables <img src="man/figures/logo.png" align="right" />
```

How I supposed to run `pkgdown::build_site()` or `pkgdown::build_home()` to take effect?  Do I need to specify a list of `override`? If not, can I add this information in the `override=` parameter? How? This is completely unclear to me in the manual.

For some reason, I end up with a `pkgdown.yml` that is missing these information bits, and eventually the links are wrong on the resulting website.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this problem. It seems that a *yml* file is created and one is required for what you say above.

In short, I think that you need to put the `_pkgdown.yml` file into the *pkgdown* folder and not the *inst* folder. All should then work if you run `pkgdown::build_site()`.

I hope this helps you.